# I'm getting quite a lot of downvotes on a question and answer I posted

Tags: discussion

Link: [C++ Reading Data into Memory when Data Format and Type is Unknown at Compile Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380174/c-reading-data-into-a-vector-in-a-class-when-format-is-unknown?noredirect=1#comment66088254_39380174)

I don't like to post on the meta about a question receiving downvotes. I don't really like it when I see similar posts on here, because I think it's usually a bit pointless to have a question about another question which was posted on the main site. However in this case I am going against my rule, as I shall explain below.

I'm getting quite a lot of downvotes on a question and answer I posted... I don't really know why. I have included a minimal example problem and have shown my research and attempted solutions to the problem. Finally I managed to get my initial idea for a solution working and posted that as an answer, however this also seems to have been poorly received by the community with more downvotes.

I added my finally working answer as I hoped other users may find it useful in the future. As an implementation of a solution to this elementary problem which could be extended at the users desire, I think the material has a lot of use and application in generality. So I find it strange that it has been downvoted, as the material has a wide scope for applications. (In contrast to a solution to a very specific problem which may never be useful to any future readers.)

One possible reason I can think of which might be the reason for this is that my initial attempts at solving the problem I was having did not compile as they contained some errors. However in my question I was asking for help solving the problems I was having. My best guess is that my "solution" to the problem was so close to being a solution, those downvoting didn't realize I hadn't solved the problem yet, and so were downvoting because they thought I thought my solution was working, when in fact it would not compile at this moment in time. (Does that make sense?)

Comment: I removed a bunch of noise from that answer. Don't rant about _"SO only caring about the end result"_ in your answer.

Comment: Within the first few lines of the answer, I see nonsense claims, like AMD processors using a different endianness than Intel processors. That makes me suspect of the quality of the remainder of the answer. Furthermore, it looks like the "answer" is a continuation of the question, in terms of numbering, presentation, and formatting. This is another standard reason for downvoting.

Comment: @CodyGray My mistake, this should have been "non-intel"

Comment: @CodyGray I've changed it - but I think you've highlighted a key problem with the SO community here. The endianness point is almost totally irrelevant to the question, and was only added as an after-thought to guard against anyone who copies and pastes the code, and then comes back crying "it's not working, nonsense values get printed on screen"! (If they use a different endianness CPU and therefore see the byte-reverse of an int.) However, even though what I wrote was incorrect because I was under the impression that AMD/Intel use a different endianness, that is no reason to downvote an

Comment: @CodyGray an entire answer - what should happen is an edit should be made or a comment added pointing out the error. The key point here being the actual important parts which make the answer an answer to the question is not wrong - a side note about something else is.

Comment: I think your main problem is that you tagged the question [c++]

Comment: [From a comment to your "answer"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380174/c-reading-data-into-a-vector-in-a-class-when-format-is-unknown?noredirect=1#comment66088249_39380175): *This is an answer - however I need to check that it compiles and runs correctly. This will take some time.* It's not a (good) answer if you don't know whether it compiles and runs correctly. I don't follow C++, but if you posted an answer in any of the tags I follow, with code that doesn't even compile, downvotes would follow fast and furious.

Comment: Your answer currently has a request for down votes in it.

Comment: I think the big thing to remember here is that SO should largely read almost like an encyclopedia to anyone who comes to your question later. The question needs to be very clearly stated and some information about what you've researched/tried so far is expected. Answers should be exactly that: answers. They need to directly address the question without any need for extra context. They also should not invite discussion. Obviously people should comment if something needs to be addressed but the answer itself should be written as though you were teaching it to a class.

Answer (score 7):

It's impossible to say for sure why other people downvoted you, but my guess is these two lines.

> What possible ways are there of approaching this problem?
>
> What are the advantages and disadvantages of each method?

Those make the question both a little bit broad and opinion based.  In addition to that, your post doesn't even need those two questions. It stands fine without them. You have a clear problem and an attempt at a solution. I'd just delete those two lines.

Comment: I could remove them, but I was specifically hoping to see multiple solutions, as I think finding multiple solutions to a problem using different ideas is interesting and can be very useful for learning purposes.

Comment: @user3728501 Then take your downvotes. ;)

Comment: Bill, I have removed those lines from my original question. It's still attracting downvotes like a sinking ship. You might be more interested to know that I posted a new question on the meta to further discuss what you have said here about downvotes being justified on the reason that posting a question containing what I would call "request for learning" is not allowed, or disapproved of, however you like to describe your justification given here. If you have an opinion on this feel free to add a comment etc.

Comment: @user3728501 open-ended questions s are off-topic here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Which question is it you are referring to when you say open ended? The original question I posted certainly isn't open ended.

Comment: The two bits I quoted above are open-ended. In my opinion, removing them fixes the question.

Comment: Oh right I understand what you're saying now. Yes I removed them quite some time ago. Still I don't think they actually make the question any more or less open ended. The question is still the same regardless of these comments as my solution isn't that great and (I hope) someone may be able to improve on it.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't understand after a very quick glance, but as I read it more carefully I realised you've misunderstood the purpose of StackOverflow.

Your question is this:

*I'm trying to accomplish X, can people please suggest ways in which I might accomplish X? Here's my working code where I have already accomplished X.*

Here's a similar way of asking your question that may have yielded less downvotes:

*I'm trying to accomplish X, here's my solution so far, but it is too slow. How can I make this more efficient?*

*I'm trying to accomplish X, here's my solution so far, but it is not easily extended, is there something I can do to make this more generic?*

You've already got a working answer and you're not asking anything specific about it. You've just asked a question and then posted an answer - what is it you're wanting people to do with that information? Without explaining what you're unhappy with, or what you would like fixed, you can't expect anyone to be able to appropriately respond.

This is what makes your question "overly broad", and is the reason for the downvotes I suspect. I want to be clear that I don't think there is anything wrong with wanting to find alternative solutions to a problem (and neither do your downvoters). They've just identified, correctly, that this isn't the appropriate forum for that kind of a discussion.

Answer (score 2):

In the current version of your post, you say:

> I would be interested to know multiple suggestions about how this problem can be solved, even though I have now solved it for myself. I think it is important to see multiple different ideas from many different programmers, as this may help to expand ones [sic] abilities and experience, aiding learning and improving ones [sic] programming abilities.

Although hardly a reason for downvoting, some downvoters may have been put off by this paragraph, which is entirely semantically vacuous, and applies implicitly and by definition to all questions posted on SO.

Answer (score -8):

I believe it is in the way you write the question while you already have an answer.

Community of SO is strict, follow the "basic rules" or get down-voted.

By "basic rules" I mean - if you have a problem, you should write small explanation about what you are trying to do, code of what you have tried and the error you are experiencing. That's it, only those 3 paragraphs. Any extra word is unneeded.

If you already have a working solution and you say "look in the answer", it kinda makes people mad because, if you already have an answer, why are you asking? then BAM. you get down-vote.

There is another community 'CodeReview' when you can write a full working code and ask for another solution maybe or just what you could do better in your solution.

For conclusion - Question should be a real question, a problem you are having with the code and not suggestions.