# Is it against the SO rules to post multiple answers which solve a problem using a different approach, idea or method?

Tags: discussion

I recently posted a question on Stack Overflow, which quite quickly attracted a large number of downvotes.

I then posted a corresponding meta question, asking as to why the downvotes might have been received.

The response I got from the meta post was the following:

> It's impossible to say for sure why other people downvoted you, but my guess is these two lines.
>
> > What possible ways are there of approaching this problem?
> >
> > What are the advantages and disadvantages of each method?
>
> Those make
>   the question both a little bit broad and opinion based. In addition to
>   that, your post doesn't even need those two questions. It stands fine
>   without them. You have a clear problem and an attempt at a solution.
>   I'd just delete those two lines.

So I partially understand the answer here. Stack Overflow tries to avoid opinion based questions for multiple reasons. For example, a question such as ***what is the best operating system to use for programming*** (one I just made up as an example) probably would get lots of downvotes and possibly removed, because it's difficult if not impossible to come up with ways of factually answering this question. Windows developers like developing on windows (probably) because there are things about windows they like. Similarly, Mac OS X and Linux developers (probably) prefer those systems due to some other opinion based reason. But I digress.

In this case, I wanted to see multiple possible methods and approaches to solving the problem I was having, as by reading other programmers code, one learns from other programmers ideas and expands ones abilities. (Essentially, I call this *learning*.) Therefore I would suggest that rather than being opinion based, this question is focused on solving a problem and learning further from others ideas.

My question is, is this against the Stack Overflow rules? My feeling is that in recent years, an attitude has emerged on Stack Overflow that once a question has an answer, it shouldn't ever attract any more answers. *If a problem has been solved then don't solve it again.* Perhaps this attitude has arisen in response to so-called reputation bait. Or for example where one user rips-off another users answer, changing it only slightly, in order to gain reputation. (AKA: Plagiarism.)

If this *is* against the rules*, then I would suggest that perhaps we should have a re-think on this. I believe that if this is the case, then it is detrimental to creativity and learning. However I certainly agree that Stack Overflow should remain resistant to plagiarism, as things are in the academic world.

*Note I mean, if asking for, etc, multiple solutions to a problem for the sake of learning, is against the rules. (I am fairly sure plagiarism is against the rules and so it should be. That's not what I'm saying here.)

I have tagged this as discussion, and hope to hear and discuss your thoughts on this. If anything is unclear please ask me a good question, and I will try to answer you.

Note I slightly modified the wording of my question to remove the following quote, due to the response received on my meta post.

> What possible ways are there of approaching this problem?
>
> What are the advantages and disadvantages of each method?

For reference, the original question can be found here: See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380174/c-reading-data-into-a-vector-in-a-class-when-format-is-unknown?noredirect=1#comment66088887_39380174)

The meta question can be found here: See this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334096/im-getting-quite-a-lot-of-downvotes-on-a-question-and-answer-i-posted/334097?noredirect=1#comment392678_334097)

Comment: The short of it is "no". I understand your frustration, and Stack Overflow certainly isn't perfect. But its narrow rules and scope exist for good reasons. I strongly encourage you to browse meta and the Stack Exchange meta; it has many interesting posts on *why* things are as they are. Also note that the SO team realises the site isn't perfect, and *are* working on it. This is pretty much what the SO documentation effort is about (that has its own problems, but its new and hopefully the problems will be addressed).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I thought the documentation would be less appropriate for my question as I thought it was supposed to be more like a wiki?

Comment: ... Bit disappointing that this is now getting downvoted without any actual comments on the points I have raised...

Comment: Documentation is not a panacea either; I don't know if your answer will fit there, as I don't fully understand the question (not a C++ guy). I didn't downvote this, but I suspect it's because similar grievances have been brought up many times before, typically without too much understanding of *why* things are as they are, and *without* a constructive idea or path forward. This is why I encouraged you to read up on meta ;-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Grievances to what? Are you suggesting the question was downvoted because it's too difficult to answer? I don't really understand what you're saying here... If so see the answer I posted... There are some ugly bits about it but it's progress at least... But maybe if you say you're not a C++ guy then reading the answer might not help you much? I don't know what your experience is so I can't comment on that.

Comment: I have no idea why you think some "attitude has emerged", much less that it might be a "rule" not to provide additional answers. Where did you get that notion?

Comment: It looks like an attempt to create a code review site.  Imagine everybody doing this, big ugh.  Use codereview.stackexchange.com to ask for a review.

Comment: I'm not sure that learning is the purpose of Stack Overflow. One of the headers on the [tour] is "Get answers to practical, detailed questions". Nothing on that page indicates that teaching/learning is the objective. Now, obviously, getting an answer to a practical, detailed question may lead to learning in most cases (although with the emphasis on copy-paste programming one could argue the opposite), but that's a side effect. If you want to learn how to program, there are a veritable cornucopia of tutorial sites out there. Stack Overflow was never meant to be everything to all programmers.

Comment: @torazaburo Having been a user of SO since it began, I can say I've witnessed a more hostile attitude emerging to some questions. Good evidence for this is - look at some of the questions that were posted when SO began, or questions which are more than 4 years old or so... Many of those questions are good questions, but for reasons XYZ have received negative attention in recent times. It's quite difficult for me to find a specific example of this for you, because I can't search for questions by age or remember the last example of this, but I have seen it over and over again.

Comment: @torazaburo I often notice that more obscure questions tagged with C++ receive lots of down/close votes - quite often my questions receive down/close votes when tagged with C++ because I have a lot of experience with the language and therefore when I ask a question it's likely to be an obscure, difficult or confusing one - and the C++ tag followers really don't like that. In this case however, I was surprised because I don't think my question is that obscure, but there are subtleties which make finding a "nice" solution difficult.

Comment: @user3728501 It seems like you're veering off target. I thought your original question was whether it makes sense or is OK to request multiple answers, whereas now you've digressed onto the topic of some alleged pandemic of down-voting.

Answer (score 7):

Your title here asks if it's legal to *post answers* with multiple competing solutions. It certainly is, and this is ubiquitous. Your question, however, asks if a *question* can *require* that. That's a horse of an entirely different color, since it implies that each answer needs to broaden its scope to include multiple solutions, which is less than ideal.

In other words, you're mistaking *the desirable set of resulting answers* for *the thing the question needs to explicitly ask for* in much the same way a tool-recommendation question does — and those have been closed for years, but tool recommendation answers *still* won't be deleted if they're good!

Ask for a way to do something, and trust SO's basic functionality to give you explanations of how that thing works and different ways and means. Maybe you'll get the best possible set of answers; maybe you won't. But you won't get a *better* one by trying to force each individual answerer to do the job of all the eventual answerers to the question. That's just not how it works. Step back a bit and just let things ride. *"You can't always get what you want / But if you try sometimes you just might find / You get what you need."*